# Java BufferedImage equivelent in Objective C/ Cocoa Touch?

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa-touch, image

Is there an equivalent of Java's `BufferedImage` class in Objective C or Cocoa Touch? I need a way to find and manipulate single pixels.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSBitmapImageRep is what you are looking for. You get this from an NSImage object.

Best